# Firebase Storage and Image View

Tags: java, android, firebase, bitmap, firebase-storage

I want to get image from Firebase Storage and than show at Image View. I trying this code but not working. Always I getting my "ERROR" toast message.
App is opening but I dont see my JPEG.

** I found one way but it is not enough for me.

If I delete  'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.3.2' from build gradle, this code working.
I need FirebaseAuth because I have User login and logout page.
Do you know another way for Firebase storage and image ?

Thank you for help.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oFUOx.jpg)

```
private StorageReference mStorageReference;
ImageView imageView;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_vardiya);

mStorageReference=FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("vardiyaandroid.jpeg");
    final File localfile;
    try {
        localfile = File.createTempFile("vardiyaandroid","jpeg");
        mStorageReference.getFile(localfile).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                Toast.makeText(vardiya.this,"Resim Hazır",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(localfile.getAbsolutePath());
                (imageView=findViewById(R.id.imageView)).setImageBitmap(bitmap);

            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(vardiya.this,"ERROR",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        });
        

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: What's the exact error message?

Comment: I dont get error message. "ERROR" message is my toast message.
APP is opening but I dont see my jpeg.

Comment: Please change the toast error to:

`Toast.makeText(vardiya.this,"ERROR: " + e.getMessage() ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();`

And then post the error message.

Comment: E/StorageException: StorageException has occurred.
    Object does not exist at location.
     Code: -13010 HttpResult: 404

Answer (score 0):

I found my false.

1. You will change this code

   mStorageReference=FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("vardiyaandroid.jpeg");

   with

mStorageReference=FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl("gs://YOURAPPID.appspot.com/vardiyaandroid.jpeg");
StorageReference pathreferance =mStorageReference.child("vardiyaandroid.jpeg");

```
and the storege rules must be this:



rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, writ, auth: if true;
    }
  }
}
```